# Cannot add avahi dependency in meson build

Tags: gnome, meson-build, avahi

I wanted to use the header files for avahi in `gnome-control-center`. However, when I add the dependency in `meson.build` file, it gives me this error.
[image]

But pkg-config seems to work on the system.
[image]

This is how I added the dependency is `meson.build`
[image]

Do I also need to configure something else?

I have already tried using
`avahi_client_dep = dependency('avahi-client', method : 'system')` but get the same error.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please consider to accepting edit suggestion from other user.

Comment: I tried a lot of things to run this on Ubuntu 22.10 but only flatpak's installation worked!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a module for avahi in the flatpak's manifest worked.